# Lock in Framework 3.5 vs 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, locking

[AFAIK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd289498%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , there is a difference between `lock` in those 2 versions.

Framework 4 added one more check if there was an exception during monitor enter ( like out of memory  exception)

And there is a `lockTaken` flag which indicates if a lock should be released (in a `finally` clause) or not ( due to fail code in a `try` clause).

Something  like

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
   Monitor.Enter (lockObj, ref lockTaken);
   ...
}
finally { if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit (lockObj); }
```

(very much similar to the `using` code (dispose...))

**But** viewing by relfector I see totally different thing :

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static void Enter(object obj, ref bool lockTaken)
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_MustBeFalse"), "lockTaken");
    }
    ReliableEnter(obj, ref lockTaken);
}
```

*where is the pattern of try , finally ?*

What am I missing ?

Comment: In the first snippet you're looking at the method call, in the second at the implementation of the method called.

Comment: @dtb this is how c# 4.0 translates a lock statement (edited the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at decompiled method that uses `lock` statement instead of looking into framework's code. So, if you'll try to decompile following method:

```
object syncRoot = new object();
void Foo()
{
  lock(syncRoot) {}
}
```

You'll see what you're expected:

```
void Foo()
{
  bool lockTaken;
  try
  {
    Monitor.Enter(syncRoot, out lockTaken);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (lockTaken)
        Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sergey. I didnt know that the compiler can emit more code than the FW code.